# extracting the number of orders for each category according to its' date by the number of the product type appeared using python

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, analytics

extracting the number of orders for each category according to its' date by the number of the product type appeared using python please if you have any other method let me know

these are the libraries i used

```
#Importing libraries 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
sns.set()
```

here is the count of each product i have

```
print(" The Total number for each product type: ")   

data.DrugType.value_counts()
```

the  output is

```
productA                      8124
productB                      3047
```

transformation of the variable frome date & time value to  date value

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Assessment_Date']).dt.date
data['date']=pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
```

here is the code i wrote to find the number of product order according to its's order date

```
print(  data.groupby('DrugType')['date'].sum() )
```

this is what i got
KEYERROR: 'date' is not a column in data

i want the out put to be like this one below

```
productA             1-11-2022         8124
productB             1-11-2022         3047
```

if you have another way to write the code to count the number of order for each category
PLEASE let me know

thank you and please do not close my question without a helpful answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with some
[reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
example data.
It has statistics similar to yours.

```
import datetime as dt
from random import randrange, seed
import pandas as pd

start = dt.datetime(2022, 1, 1)
seed(0)

data = pd.DataFrame([
        dict(
            DrugType="product" + ("A" if randrange(100) < 73 else "B"),
            date=start + dt.timedelta(days=randrange(365)),
            qty=1,
        )
        for _ in range(11_171)    
])
```

Now, it's not entirely clear what you're looking for.
Here are two possibilities.

```
>>> data.groupby(["date", "DrugType"]).count()
                     qty
date       DrugType     
2022-01-01 productA   20
           productB   15
2022-01-02 productA   26
           productB   10
...                  ...
2022-12-30 productA   24
           productB    8
2022-12-31 productA   24
           productB    9

[730 rows x 1 columns]
```

That's explaining that last year every day
we sold two kinds of drugs, typically more of A than B.

Alternatively, perhaps you were looking for something
simpler, focused on just a single Series.

```
>>> data.groupby(["date"]).qty.count()
date
2022-01-01    35
2022-01-02    36
2022-01-03    27
              ..
2022-12-29    31
2022-12-30    32
2022-12-31    33
Name: qty, Length: 365, dtype: int64
```

Which shows that typically we sold
a little more than 30 units each day,
and the daily totals match the subtotals
that were broken out above.

Comment: please can you take a look on this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74959530/how-to-compute-precision-recall-and-f1-score-of-an-balanced-logistic-regression  please https://stackoverflow.com/users/8431111/j-h