# How to compute precision,recall and f1 score of an balanced logistic regression model in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, data-science, precision-recall

i need my  precision,recall and f1 score results to be like the output below

```
precision  0.98
recall     0.98 
f1 score   0.93
```

the numbers are just an example

here is my data head
[image]

here is my code

```
    #training and test sample :
x1_training_data, x1_test_data, y1_training_data, y1_test_data = train_test_split(x1_data, y1_data, test_size = 0.3)

    # Estimation result:
logit_model=sm.Logit(y1_training_data,x1_training_data)
result1=logit_model.fit()
print(result1.summary2())

    # Model Evaluation:
logreg=LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(x1_training_data,y1_training_data)
y1_pred=logreg.predict(x1_test_data)
print('Logistic regression model accuracy:{:.2f}'.format(logreg.score(x1_test_data,y1_test_data)))
print("Logistic Regression F1 Score :",f1_score(y1_test_data,logreg.predict(x1_test_data),average=None))
```

here is my results of the code

```
logistic Regression Accuracy after undersampling : 0.902297169964584
Logistic Regression F1 Score after undersampling : [0.90023556 0.9042753 ]
```

i had two numbers for the F1 score i wanted to be just one number and i do not know how
and i tried to find a code to find out the precision or the recall and i could not find any

please help me at least with the F1 score output
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From sklearn import the metrics

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
```

Split data and train the model

```
#training and test sample :
x1_training_data, x1_test_data, y1_training_data, y1_test_data = train_test_split(x1_data, y1_data, test_size = 0.3)

# Estimation result:
logit_model=sm.Logit(y1_training_data,x1_training_data)
result1=logit_model.fit()
print(result1.summary2())

# Model Evaluation:
logreg=LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(x1_training_data,y1_training_data)
y1_pred=logreg.predict(x1_test_data)
```

Print the metrics, here for the average parameter you can change it check [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html) for details

```
print('precision: %.2f' % precision_score(y1_data, y1_pred,average='weighted'))
print('recall: %.2f' % recall_score(y1_data, y1_pred,average='weighted'))
print('f1_score: %.2f' % f1_score(y1_data, y1_pred,average='weighted'))
```